# Remove null values using JMESPath

Tags: json, null, jmespath

```json
[
  {
    "key": 111,
    "Students_Info": [{
      "recordId": 111
    }],
    "Adress_Info": {
      "position": 1,
      "city": null
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 222,
    "Students_Info": [{
      "recordId": 222
    }],
    "Adress_Info": {
      "position": 2,
      "city": "Delhi"
    }
  }
]
```

How do I filter the `null` values and remove them from the JSON using JMESPath query?

Comment: What do you want to remove exactly? Could you provide a desired output?

Comment: It would also be nice to have a valid JSON input, for the moment being, it is not, as `Delhi` is not quoted.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε- Thanks for pointing out. Updated and I would like to have the output which has city name and remove the object Address_Info which has the city name null

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to filter out the objects having empty `Adress_Info.city`, you can use a *[filter projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections)*.

The query:

```
[?Adress_Info.city]
```

On the given input would yield:

```json
[
  {
    "key": 222,
    "Students_Info": [
      {
        "recordId": 222
      }
    ],
    "Adress_Info": {
      "position": 2,
      "city": "Delhi"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Its a huge array and this is one of it. I need to remove globally from all the objects with different keys. So individual filter isn not a good option in this case